# How do I change the block template for specific theorem environments (LaTeX beamer)

Tags: latex, beamer

The amsthm theorem environments (theorem,example,proof,solution,...) make blocks on beamer slides.  The default is that example environments use a different template (block example) than theorem or solution or proof (block).

How do I make solution use a different template like "block solution" that I can define?

**Edit:** Thanks to those who answered.  I haven't implemented a workaround yet but it seems like there are two ideas:

- Redefine the `\th@foo` command for a theorem-like environment named `foo`.  The new command should redefine `\inserttheoremblockenv` to be the desired block environment.  See `beamerbasetheorems.sty` (around line 63) for how this is done specifically for `example`.
- Redefine the `theorem begin` and `theorem end` template to look up the correct theorem block environment based on the global variable `\inserttheoremname` (see `beamerinnerthemedefault.sty`).  The lookup table could be kept in a `pgfkeys` registry.  This approach would be a bit higher-level and wouldn't involve any commands with `@` in them; however, YAGNI comes to mind.

Answer (score 2):

As seen in `beamerbasetheorems.sty`:

```
\documentclass[notheorems]{beamer}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\translate{Theorem}}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{\translate{Example}}

% or

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\translate{Theorem}}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{\translate{Example}}

% or

\theoremstyle{example}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\translate{Theorem}}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{\translate{Example}}
```

Whatever style you like. You can also change the appearance of the [alert|example]block:

```
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=blue,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{block body alerted}{fg=blue,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{block body example}{fg=blue,bg=white}
```

(Not tried it, just looked into the beamer sources)

**EDIT:** Still not sure want you want to do, but you can define your own theorem styles:

```
\makeatletter
\def\th@something{%
  \normalfont % body font
  \def\inserttheoremblockenv{alertblock}  
}
\theoremstyle{something}
\newtheorem{warn}[theorem]{WARNING}
\makeatother

\begin{warn}[Attention please]
This is dangerous
\end{warn}
```

(This works, I tested it)

You have 3 predefined blocks which you can customize using \defbeamertemplate. Look into the sources and the documentation on how to do this. If you need more block environments, see `basebeamerlocalstructure.sty`:

```
  \newenvironment<>{alertblock}[1]{%
    \begin{actionenv}#2%
      \def\insertblocktitle{#1}%
      \par%
      \mode<presentation>{%\usebeamerfont{block}%
        \setbeamercolor{local structure}{parent=alerted text}}%
      \usebeamertemplate{block alerted begin}}
    {\par%
      \usebeamertemplate{block alerted end}%
    \end{actionenv}}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: What I really want to do is create a new alternative to theorem/example/alert blocks.

beamerbasetheorems.sty overrides one of amsthm's internals so as to use a "theorem begin" template when a theorem-like enviroment is begin.  That template starts a block environment named '\insertblockenv'.  This macro is defined in beamerbasetheorems.sty to be "block", and only in an override of an internal '\th@example' is the '\insertblockenv' macro redefined to "exampleblock".  So those are your choices: exampleblock if the theoremstyle is example, block o/w.

Maybe the template can be adapted?

Comment: Do you want to change an existing block environment or define a new block environment?

Comment: I want to change an existing block environment.  I don't want "theorem" and "solution" (for instance) to be in the same beamercolorbox. 

I won't have a chance to get back to this for another day or two, but I think something can be accomplished using PGF's key registry within the `theorem begin` template.

Comment: Or, maybe just hack \th@solution to change \insertblockenv like  beamerbasetheorems.sty does with \th@example.

Comment: Is what you are trying to accomplish in my edit? Do you need more block environments or help to create new ones?